# Data not displayed when fetched from a MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm new in stackoverflow, so I'm sorry if i'm doing wrong.

Issue : I've create a function in PHP with HTML, but I dunno why my data not show.

here's the code :

```
<?php
<!-- here is `require blabla.php` -->
    function showName(){
            $sql="SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE 1";
            $result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $var=$row['company_name'];
            echo $var;
        }
?>

<!-- HTML Code -->

<td><b>Company Name: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php showName(); ?>" id="name" required name="name"></td>
```

--***EDIT***--

`myConnection.php`

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pos");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "pos");
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to turn on error reporting. It would likely tell you that `$connection` is undefined. You need to feed the connection into the function. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: Did you assign something to `$connection`? What is the error message?

Comment: What does it show now.  Seems you need to make the connection variable a global variable. Also add a loop before returning results

Comment: @Rasclatt when i've add ur code, there's no error showing in interface

Comment: @Am.rez no error sir, just the data in database not showing, i've add _Rasclatt_ code in my file, but still no error showing, i dunno what happen

Comment: In your function, do this. global $connection

Comment: @Akin i've read the doc for add ur code [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), and the error is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$connection' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\companySettings.php on line 10`, what happen with my connection? when another scripts work fine

Comment: any idea please?? i've read any tutorial but not yet find out how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**maincode.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'myconnection.php' ;

function showName(){
    global $connection;
        $sql="SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE 1";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
        }
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $var=$row['company_name'];
        echo $var;
    }
?>

<td><b>Company Name: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php showName(); ?>" 
id="name" required name="name"></td>
```

**myconnection.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","");
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "pos");
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add `myConnection.php`.

```
<?php
function showName(){
        require 'myConnection.php';
        $sql="SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE 1";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
        }
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $var=$row['company_name'];
        echo $var;
    }
?>

<!-- HTML Code -->

<td><b>Company Name: </b></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php showName(); ?>" id="name" required name="name"></td>
```